# Region deployment from Openstack Autopilot Test Drive fails at "Deploying 'mysql' service"

Tags: juju, maas, openstack, openstack-autopilot, testdrive

I am currently trying to deploy an Openstack Cloud using Ubuntu's autopilot test drive. I have followed the instructions in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-autopilot-testdrive.

They deployment is made using KVM as the compute service, vSwitch as the network service, swift as the object storage service, and iSCSI as the block storage service. There are 6 nodes on my network which follow the simple naming convention "node-x". Seven, counting the controller node. The network they are all connected to is the 10.0.0.0/24.

However, when I enter Landscape to actually deploy the region, the process fails at 96%. The processes which fail are:

- Deploying 'mysql' service
- Add unit to 'mysql' service on 'node-1.myautopilot
- Creating a Landscape admin user

I imagine only one of the three is the actual root of the problem, but I have little to no experience viewing the logs (not to mention, there are several of them).
The errors I have found in the logs are the following:

**juju-sync.log**

```
Jan 18 12:13:11 juju-sync-1 INFO  Unit mysql/0 has been updated: address = 10.0.0.82, machine_id = 0/lxc/5, state = error, state_info = hook failed: "shared-db-relation-changed"
```

**all-machines.log**

```
unit-mysql-0[912]: 2016-01-18 12:13:05 ERROR juju.worker.uniter.operation runhook.go:107 hook "shared-db-relation-changed" failed: exit status 1
```

In fact there were many more errors, all of them relating to `no relation id specified`

**job-handler.log**

> Jan 18 10:58:13 job-handler-1 ERR  Got error while handling job#012Traceback (most recent call last):#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 423, in errback#012    self._startRunCallbacks(fail)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 490, in _startRunCallbacks#012    self._runCallbacks()#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 577, in _runCallbacks#012    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1155, in gotResult#012    _inlineCallbacks(r, g, deferred)#012---  ---#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1097, in _inlineCallbacks#012    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/failure.py", line 389, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator#012    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)#012  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/activity/jobs.py", line 18, in run#012    yield self._update_activity(account_id, activity_id)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py", line 196, in _worker#012    result = context.call(ctx, function, *args, **kwargs)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 118, in callWithContext#012    return self.currentContext().callWithContext(ctx, func, *args, **kw)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/python/context.py", line 81, in callWithContext#012    return func(*args,**kw)#012  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/storm/twisted/transact.py", line 76, in _wrap#012    result = function(*args, **kwargs)#012  File "/opt/canonical/landscape/canonical/landscape/model/activity/jobs.py", line 28, in _update_activity#012    activity._update_progress_after_child_changed()#012exceptions.AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_update_progress_after_child_changed'

I have made sure that all VMs have sufficient resources allocated (they did from the start, as I am using the VM templates provided by Ubuntu). Furthermore, they can all access the internet.

If additional information is required, I will supply it as soon as possible.

Has anyone encountered this problem and knows how to solve it? Or, in any case, any further debugging steps I can take to find a solution to the problem?

Thank you.

P.S. If this question doesn't belong on this platform, I apologize and please redirect me to the relevant one.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please [file a bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/landscape/+filebug?tags=cloud-install-failure) and attach the full tarball of logs that the Autopilot surfaces in the UI?

Comment: Just did so. Hopefully a solution will be found. Thank you!